# Kafka long polling

Tags: long-polling, apache-kafka

I'm looking at kafka to implement a low-latency message queue, and I've been reading up about consumer long polling. However, there are no examples about how to actually use long polling, or what options you need to set to enable it. How do you enable long polling using the kafka java api?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't have to enable it per say since it is the default behavior of the kafka consumer. What you need to set in your configuration is `fetch.wait.max.ms`.

Two values are important to achieve what you want:

- `fetch.min.bytes`: The broker will wait for this amount of data to fill BEFORE it sends the response to the consumer client.
- `fetch.max.wait.ms`: The broker will wait for this amount of time BEFORE sending a response to the consumer client, unless it has enough data to fill the response (`fetch.message.min.bytes`)

A response will be sent to the consumer once either of these values is reached. The longest possible fetch request time will always be `fetch.max.wait.ms`.

Look for more configuration options in [Kafka Consumer Configs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs)

The kafka user mailing list is a also good option for questions like this.

Comment: quick question: lets say `fetch_max_wait_ms` time has elapsed and we still have not reached the min data byte size, what does the consumer do? Continue waiting or just accept the data that is already present?

Comment: @lollerskates Same question I have and second thing what is difference between `fetch.wait.max.ms` and the time we provide in `consumer.poll(<what is this time>)?` Is there anything related between them.

Comment: The property is 'fetch.max.wait.ms' instead of 'fetch.wait.max.ms' atleast in Kafka version 2.3+